# Regex batch: insert space between letters and numbers

Tags: regex, batch-file

I have filenames like so

```
Chi10febbraio2021
ChiK11Marzo2021
```

I use this script (you can find jrepl.bat [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044))

```
for %%a in (*) do ( 
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('echo %%a^|jrepl.bat "([A-Z])" " $1"') do (
     ren "%%a" "%%b"
  )
)
```

to insert a space between uppercase and lowercase letters in this way

```
Chi10febbraio2021
Chi K11Marzo2021
```

I try to add also a space between letters and numbers in this way

```
 Chi 10 febbraio 2021
 Chi K 11 Marzo 2021
```

changing `"([A-Z])" " $1"')` into `([a-z])([0-9])" "$1 $2"')`

but it return me

```
Chi 10Febbraio 2021
```

when I expect

```
Chi 10 Febbraio 2021
```

Comment: You realize the developer of `JREPL` does regularly answer questions on DosTips.com as well as here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `([A-Z])` with `" $1"` will not *"insert a space between uppercase and lowercase letters"*, it will insert a space before any uppercase latter, which is a completely different thing.

You can't "extend" this expression to also insert spaces between letters and numbers, because inserting spaces between types of characters is not what it does in the first place. Your input just accidentally is formed in a way that "inserting a space before each uppercase latter" kind of does the right thing.

I've not looked into the implementation of `jrepl.bat`, but the page you've linked says it's a JScript/batch hybrid, which leads me to the assumption that internally it uses the regular expression engine of the Windows Script Host.

If that's the case, this regex should work.

```
([a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])|([a-z])(?=[A-Z])|([0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])
```

to be replaced with `"$1$2$3 "`. You might run into syntax errors when you paste that into your batch file as-is, I'll let you figure out the escaping yourself.

The regex works by covering the three cases that can happen:

1. a letter followed by a number - `([a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])`
2. a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase - `([a-z])(?=[A-Z])`
3. a number followed by a letter - `([0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])`

In all three cases we need to append a space. The cases are mutually exclusive - when one case matches, the other two do not. This means we can use all three groups `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` back-to-back in the replacement string, only one of them will contain anything, and we don't care which one it was. This is how the `"$1$2$3 "` works.

Comment: Great ! Thank you, now I understand what it was problem